# xCopy into the top folder of a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I running an `xcopy` command to transfer from one file to the other.

```
xcopy /s "c:\users\documents\thisfile.txt" "d:\otherfiles\1.2.1"
```

I'd like to be able to just copy the file into the most recent folder in the `otherfiles` directory rather than hard coding it every time a new version folder is created. These are versions numbers and these tend to just increase.

Is this entirely possible?

Comment: it is possible. Do the folders all only have version numbers as per your example?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yes, each folder only has the version number as it's name

Comment: ok, and then do they come as double numerics i.e `1.2.21` or only single always? also, datewise, do the later version folders always get created after the previous, or can version `1.1.1` be created as a folder, after `1.1.2` etc?

Comment: They just come as single numerics. I do tend to create the folder after. When i'm done with a version (1.4.0 let's say) I then create then the new version (1.4.1). There's not much reason for me to keep using the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it is possible to check the versions of the directories, but that will take a bit more code as we cannot simply remove the dots to get a numeric value and compare to the next. The reason being, considering versions `1.2.3` and `1.23` if we remove the dots to make it a matchable numeric value, both these will end up being being `123` therefore each version section would need to be tested.

However, based on your comments to my questions, you create new versions as folders, and therefor it ia sortable by date, so simply run a `dir` command and sort by created date. It will set the latest folder as the variable you need:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o:d D:\otherfiles') do set "myvar=%%i"
xcopy /s "c:\users\documents\thisfile.txt" "d:\otherfiles\%myvar%"
```

Comment: I will give this a go and report back!

Comment: Sure, for now, do `echo` infront of `xcopy` to echo the result instead of actual copying of it, just to test.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this in PowerShell, it is possible. This would require PowerShell 3.0 or higher. It can be done with 2.0, but would require changes. Hopefully, you are on or can upgrade to a modern-day version of PowerShell.

When you are confident that the file will be copied correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
$fn = 'C:/src/t/xxx.txt'
$destbasedir = 'C:/src/t/lastdir'

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $destbasedir |
    Sort-Object -Property Name |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $fn -Destination $_.FullName -Whatif }
```

This could be put into a .bat file script.

```
SET "FN=C:\src\t\xxx.txt"
SET "DESTBASEDIR=C:\src\t\lastdir"

powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path %DESTBASEDIR% |" ^
        "Sort-Object -Property Name |" ^
        "Select-Object -Last 1 |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "%FN%" -Destination "$_.FullName" -Whatif }"
```